# How to visualise the structure of a TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a simple model for a project which takes in some weather data and predicts a temperature. The structure is the following:

- 24 inputs with 10 features (one input per hour so 24 hours of input data)
- 1 output being a temperature

The model works, I'm all fine with that, however I need to present the way the model works and I'm unsure how some values I see about the model describe it. I'm struggling to visually represent the inner structure (as in the neurons or nodes).

Here is the model (The static input_shape is not set statically in my code, it is purely to help answer the question):

```
forward_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=32, return_sequences=True)
backward_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=32, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True)
bilstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(forward_layer, backward_layer=backward_layer, input_shape=(24, 10)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=False),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
```

Note that the reason I seperated the layers for the `Bidirectional` is because I am running this with TFLite and had issues if the two weren't pre-defined but the inner workings are the same as far as I understand it.

Now as some experts have probably already figured out just looking at this, the input shape is `(32, 24, 10)` and the output shape is `(32, 1)` where the input is under the (batch_size, sequence_length, features) format and the output is under the (batch_size, units) format.

As well as I feel I understand what the numbers represent, I can't quite wrap my head around how the model would "look". I mainly struggle to differentiate the structure during training and during predictions.

Here are the ideas I have (note that I will be describing the model based on neurons):

- Input is a 24x10 DataFrame
- The input is therefore 240 values which can be seen as 24 sets of 10 neurons ? (Not sure I'm right here)
- `return_sequences` means that the 240 values propagate throughout the model ? (Still not sure here)
- The 'neuron' structure would ressemble this:

```
Input(240 neurons) -> BiLSTM(240 neurons) ->
Dropout(240 neurons, 20% drop rate) -> LSTM(240 neurons) ->
Dropout(240 neurons, 20% drop rate) -> LSTM(240 neurons) ->
Dropout(240 neurons, 20% drop rate) -> LSTM(240 neurons) ->
Dropout(? neurons, 20% drop rate) -> Dense(1 neurons) = Output
```

If I'm not mistaken, the `Dropout` layer isn't a layer strictly speaking but it stops (in this case) 20% of the input neurons (or output, I'm not sure) from activating 20% of the output neurons.

I'd really appreciate the help on visualising the structure so thanks in advance to any brave soul ready to help me out

**EDIT**

Here is an example of what I am trying to get out of the numbers. **Note** that this image **ONLY** represents the first BiLSTM layer, not the whole model.

[image: Here is an example visualisation]

The `x ?` in the image represent what I'm trying to understand, ie how many layers are there and how many neurons are there in each layer

Comment: You can use [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs) for this.

Comment: I have tried and unfortunately, the results it returned were far from expected

Comment: You can see the model's graph with nodes and their inputs, outputs and shapes. So I am not sure how that differs from what you want.

Comment: The graph resulting from my execution didn't show any LSTM cells

Comment: Please show an example image of what kind of visualization you expect.

Comment: It should be added to the edited question now